# How do I select groups of customer references that don't use a particular service?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using the following table (customer_table):

| customer_ref | product | service |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PI-003 | cube | streaming |
| PI-722 | cube | streaming |
| PI-723 | cube | streaming |
| PI-724 | cube | streaming |
| PI-724 | pyramid | download |
| PI-725 | cube | streaming |
| PI-727 | cube | streaming |
| PI-728 | cube | streaming |
| PI-729 | cube | streaming |
| PI-729 | pyramid | download |
| PI-730 | cube | streaming |
| PI-730 | sphere | radio |

How do I select **groups** of customer references that don't use a download as a service?

If I do:
SELECT customer_ref FROM customer_table WHERE service <> download

It will return customer_ref PI-724 and PI-729 which do have a service that isn't download but I don't want to return them because under the same customer_ref they do have a service that is download - if that makes sense.

Under my parameters I want to return the following customer_ref:

| customer_ref |
| --- |
| PI-003 |
| PI-722 |
| PI-723 |
| PI-725 |
| PI-727 |
| PI-728 |
| PI-730 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jointure way

```
SELECT c1.customer_ref  
FROM customer_table  c1
LEFT JOIN customer_table  c2 ON c1.customer_ref=c2.customer_ref AND c2.service='download'
WHERE c2.customer_ref IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below using aggregation

```
select customer_ref from
group by customer_ref
having sum(case when service='download' then 1 else 0 end)=0
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is essentially the same what I have initially tried (SELECT customer_ref FROM customer_table WHERE service <> download) but you have re-labelled  'download' as an integer - It still returns customer ref PI-724 and PI-729 which I do not want in my output

Comment: @sham have you checked it ??and btw both are not same

Comment: @sham shared with data in db-fiddle i am showing you that both are not same

Comment: Apologies - error on my part, it is working

Comment: @sham then why didn't mark it accepted

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate and using `bool_and()` in the having clause:

```
select customer_ref
from the_table
group by customer_ref
having bool_and(service <> 'download');
```

`bool_and(service <> 'download')` will only return `true` if all services of the customer_ref are not equal to download

Comment: perfect thank you

Answer (score 0):

Set operation can help you

```
select customer_ref from customer_table
EXCEPT /* = MINUS */
select customer_ref from customer_table 
where service = 'download'
```

It is as easy as you would formulate it: all customers *except* those that used *download*.

Note also that the set operations return distinct key, so you do not nead to used `distinct` or some `group by`

Comment: Yes @a_horse_with_no_name that is waht I meant. Thanks for pointing me to the standard.